# Why does opening the camera app pause music or podcasts on an iPhone 6s?

Tags: camera, iphone

When listening to audio like music, podcasts, or an audio book on an iPhone 6s running iOS 9 the audio pauses when I open the camera app to take a photo. This doesn't happen on other devices. Is there a way to stop it from pausing?

Comment: Likes like an fruit stand employee on twitter confirm that they see it as a bug.

Comment: Tweet: https://twitter.com/eharris/status/712279668351586304

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Live photos use the microphone to record sound as well as video when you take a picture. Look at the camera settings when you open the app to see whether video is going to happen (or already be happening since it records video from before you press the shutter).

There appears to be a bug (that hasn't been fixed yet as of iOS 9.3) on that hardware that makes iPhone 6S worse than others - it pauses even when you are aware of the video aspects and request a non-live photo and non-video recording setting.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 10 the camera app no longer pauses audio on Live Photo capable devices.